# Django make dynamic Q object by list elements

Tags: python, django, list, recursion

I want to make dynamic q objects by given list.

```
tag_list = ["t1"] # tag list element length is 1
result_list = []
q_objs_list = []
# In this case, I want to make list like below..

# some def needed to do below
q_objs = Q()
q_objs &= Q(tag="1")
result_list.append(q_objs)
q_objs_list.append(1) #because positive q_objs is only when tag "1" 1case.

q_objs = Q()
q_objs &= ~Q(tag="1")
result_list.append(q_objs)
q_objs_list.append(0) #because positive q_objs is nothing

#>>> len(result_list) >>> 2

# In this case, list length is 2 and I want to get 4 results list.
tag_list = ["1", "2"]
result_list = []
q_objs_list = []

# some def needed to do below
q_objs = Q()
q_objs &= Q(tag="1")
q_objs &= Q(tag="2")
result_list.append(q_objs)
q_objs_list.append(2) #because positive q_objs is only when tag "1", "2" 2cases.

q_objs = Q()
q_objs &= Q(tag="1")
q_objs &= ~Q(tag="2")
result_list.append(q_objs)
q_objs_list.append(1) #1 positive case

q_objs = Q()
q_objs &= ~Q(tag="1")
q_objs &= Q(tag="2")
result_list.append(q_objs)
q_objs_list.append(1) #1 positive case

q_objs = Q()
q_objs &= ~Q(tag="1")
q_objs &= ~Q(tag="2")
result_list.append(q_objs)
q_objs_list.append(0) # no positive case
#>>> len(result_list) >>> 2 * 2
```

In my case, I don't know what tag_list will be given to me. It could be `["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"]`, `["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6"]` or something else.

So I have to prepare many case dynamically..

How can I do that?

There could be too many cases so that It is hard to me.
I think recursion would be goods choice, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: the logic for generating the Q object is not clear here. Can you give more details on that?

Comment: @ruddra It's just switch on or off for all given tag_list elements... If tag_list = ["a", "b"], so that "a" could be on or off, and "b" could be on or off so that len(result_list) can be 2*2 -> 4.. Sorry for my poor explanation